# Next.js overriding HTML tag default style with bootstrap html tag style

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have some problems in the next js with CSS. I am using the `bootstrap watch flatly` style in my next JS project. I have installed `npm I bootswatch` in my project and imported CSS in `_app.js` as `import "bootswatch/dist/flatly/bootstrap.min.css";`.

[image]

now every style is working fine when it uses className. but the default `<a>` style of flatly has been overrode by HTML's `<a>` default styles. You will better understand with the given Screenshots.

[image]

My browser is preloading `http://localhost:3000/_next/static/css/styles.chunk.css?ts=1596982084733`, then flatly style.

[image]
any help will be appreciated.